# Include \markup in define-music-function

Tags: lilypond, lily-scheme

I want a custom `\breathe` sign that can be freely positioned, like:

[image: staff with comma type breath mark]

I have some shortcut code for this:

```
place = #(define-music-function (parser location xy)
          (pair?)
          #{
            \once \override TextScript.extra-offset = #xy
          #})

comma = \markup \musicglyph "comma"
```

used as `\place #'(2 . 0) a2-\comma`.
However, it would be much nicer to be able to just write `a2-\comma #'(2 . 0)`.
Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works here:

```
comma = #(define-event-function (parser location xy)
          (pair?)
          #{
            \tweak extra-offset #xy ^ \markup \musicglyph "comma"
          #})


{ a2\comma #'(2 . 0) }
```